# how to get the values from database/controller on selected option in dropdown in Adonis Js with Edge template engine

Tags: microsoft-edge, adonis.js

I am trying to get the values from database on selected option from drop-down in adonis js with Edge template engine. 
I have populated the view like this

```
<select class="select" class="form-control" name="category_id" required onchange="whatToDo()">
                                <option selected disabled value="">Select Category</option>
                                @each(cat in categories)
                                <option value="{{cat.category_id}}" >{{cat.category_name}}</option>
                                @endeach
                            </select>
```

I have to fill the data in checkbox like this

```
<div class=" pr-5">
                                        <label class="theme ">Device Aplha_Remeo</label>
                                        <input class="fl-right cursor" type="checkbox">
                                    </div>
```

I am unable to understand that how to get the updated values on-change of value in dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, it seems that you are using edge.js to render the view, if that is the case, please check [the official document](https://edge.adonisjs.com/docs/data-locals) to find how to send request in the onchange event.

Besides, from my point of view, in the whatToDo() JavaScript method, you could use [the JQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method to call the controller methods and get the data, then to do something. Here are some relate resource, you could refer to them:

[Call Controller Action on DropDownList Change (SelectedIndexChanged)](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Call-Controller-Action-on-DropDownList-Change-SelectedIndexChanged.aspx)

[Dynamically Bind The DropDownList On Change Event In ASP.NET MVC 5](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dynamically-bind-the-dropdownlist-on-change-event-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: their documentation still needs to be more clear. However, I am trying to use jquery way